# Cobertura statistics per developer

Tags: java, maven, cobertura

do you know if there is some tool or maven plugin allowing to get cobertura data and specify it by developer? I know there is maven-blame-plugin but this is for findbugs, checkstyle and pmd reports. Do we have something similar for cobertura reports?

Thank you.

Comment: This is something that should be done on CI server (Jenkins, Hudson, TeamCity etc) probably by Sonar.

Comment: Piotr, thank you for comment, right and I need to know what should be run in order to get this statistics. Sonar has plugin but this is commercial. Perhaps there is something available which is not commercial?